# Image from server to LocalFile in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, memorystream

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT) App**.

I am getting the url of image from server. I want to save the image from this url to localstorage file.

```
string PictureUrlFromServer= "http://www.server.com/images/abc.png";
```

I wrote this:

```
StorageFolder StorageFolderObject = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(LocalCache, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            StorageFile StorageFileObject = await StorageFolderObject.CreateFileAsync(LocalProfilePicName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

After it what to do?

**EDIT:**

I even tried using below code, but its not working:

```
StorageFolder StorageFolderObject = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(LocalCache, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile StorageFileObject = await StorageFolderObject.CreateFileAsync(LocalProfilePicName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        HttpClient HttpClientObject = new HttpClient();

        HttpClientObject.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
        Uri UriObject = new Uri(_BitmapImageUriSource);
        HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessageObject = await HttpClientObject.GetAsync(UriObject);
        HttpResponseMessageObject.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseBuffer = await HttpResponseMessageObject.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();

        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(StorageFileObject, responseBuffer);
```

**Error:
Access denied on StorageFileObject**

Comment: Have you tried to [Download a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj152726.aspx)?

Comment: Thankyou, but that could be used in background transfer operations. I have to donwload a simple 10kb userprofile picture and save into localstorage file

Comment: The first method described there uses HttpClient - I think it should fullfill your needs.

Comment: Shall i use ReadAsInputStreamAsync or ReadAsBufferAsync instead of ReadAsStringAsync to read the image. and then how to save into storagefile?

Comment: I used Bitmap BitmapObject= new Bitmap(Uri); Now my image is in BitmapObject. How to convert this into Storage file?

Answer (score 1):

To download file from web, you can use `HttpClient`.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // Create HttpClient
byte[] buffer = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(PictureUrlFromServer); // Download file

StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Image.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); // Create local file
using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // Save
```

Comment: GetByteArrayAsync does not exist in Windows.Web.HttpClient

Comment: Have you added this namespace? `using System.Net.Http;`

Comment: Use of networking APIs requires the ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability to be defined in the application manifest.

Comment: So, you have to go to your *Package.appxmanifest* file in your project and add this capablitity. When you open the file, go to *Capabilities* tab and select *Internet(Clien & Server)*.

Comment: Its already enabled sir, in both Windows and as well as in Windows Phone project

Comment: Are you sure it's Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT) App? Maybe you use Silverlight? It's not possible that my code doesn't work. It's basis.

Comment: I am using WINDOWS RUNTIME/Universal app